# Not Unique Table Alias error in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

### error table

```
id, loc, no, mesg, psg, stu, auth
```

### user table

```
id, name, sname, ptg
```

id's are primary keys, ptg and psg have same records,

And this is my SQL syntax that I use in Swing project,

```
String SQL = SELECT error.id, user.name, user.sname, error.loc, error.no, error.msg 
                FROM error, user
                WHERE error.stu = '1'
                AND (user.ptg = error.psg AND error.auth = '5'
```

Error is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Not unique table/alias: 'error'
```

Comment: Could be the double quote in your where clause.  Or maybe error is a reserved word and has to be escaped.

Comment: Can you edit the question an put in the exact error message?

Comment: i added the error message, this sql is running sometimes, and sometimes dont, i dont understand why?

Comment: Or maybe it's the missing bracket after '5'.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in this query. 
The first, and most important, is the JOIN clause without a condition:

***"FROM error, user"***

When you wish to join two tables using a comma instead of a JOIN command, put your linking condition in the WHERE clause:

***"FROM error, user WHERE error.userid = user.id"***

Second error is the double quote (") after '1'. Remove it.

Third error is the unclosed bracket "(" in the last line. Remove it.

Try this and post here the results.

Cheers

Comment: ty m8, duble quote and ( are my fault i will try this.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Can we close this? Cheers